# C++/Linux hook library that supports classes

Tags: linux, c++

I've found this...

https://github.com/kubo/funchook/wiki/List-of-API-Hook-Libraries

...but they appear to be designed around global functions only.  Is there an equivalent that works for C++ class methods on Linux?